# How do I troubleshoot my Internet traffic?

Tags: windows-7, internet

I'm running Windows 7. Is there a way for me to see which currently running programs communicate via the Internet (either sending or receiving data) and how much data they are transferring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/):

> Wireshark is the world's foremost network protocol analyzer. It lets you capture and interactively browse the traffic running on a computer network. It is the de facto (and often de jure) standard across many industries and educational institutions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) :

> TCPView is a Windows program that will
>   show you detailed listings of all TCP
>   and UDP endpoints on your system,
>   including the local and remote
>   addresses and state of TCP
>   connections. On Windows Server 2008,
>   Vista, and XP, TCPView also reports
>   the name of the process that owns the
>   endpoint. TCPView provides a more
>   informative and conveniently presented
>   subset of the Netstat program that
>   ships with Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view just HTTP traffic, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) may be simpler to use.

> What is Fiddler?
>   Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect all HTTP(S) traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.