# Is there a program or browser plugin to speedup download speed within a browser like orbit downloader?

Tags: troubleshooting, internet-connection, bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I troubleshoot my internet trafic?](https://superuser.com/questions/244972/how-do-i-troubleshoot-my-internet-trafic)
>   [What can I do about a slow shared internet connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/343816/what-can-i-do-about-a-slow-shared-internet-connection)

I am using internet within a residence, and the network setup has problems:

- During low usage periods, I works fine.
- During high usage (approx between 12h00 and 23h30), the connexion has a wierd behaviour:

Connections via a browser are slow (flash video, webpages, web downloads), whereas others connections such a skype or online games are fine.

Interestingly, if I download a file via a browser (for example, a 30MB install file), the download speed is high during 1 or 2sec, and then it stops. Sometimes, it doesn't stop, but the rate is low (~100kb/sec).

I can overcome the problem of downloads by using [orbit downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) and paste in the url, and orbit downloads it at a continuous 2 or 3MB/sec rate.

So I have 2 questions:

- How can I troubleshoot what is the connection problem ?
- Does a program like orbit exists to speed up browser bandwidth ? (for seeing web pages and/or flash videos)

Comment: A private company is in charge (www.studentcom.co.uk), I have submitted a ticket but had no response.

Comment: @techie007 I disagree, here I am asking for a specific program that has a specific purpose.

Comment: There: "I wonder if there are some software that can diagnose network and help troubleshooting", Here: "How can I troubleshoot what is the connection problem?".  There: "I also wonder if they are software to soak up more bandwith like orbit, but for the whole browser", Here: "Does a program like orbit exists to speed up browser bandwidth?". You should edit your previous one (and request reopening if you'd like) instead of reposting the same question.  You should also aim to keep to one question per question, helps get better answers. :)

Comment: If you agree that this question is different that [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/119752/internet-connection-too-slow), all I have to do is delete [my previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/343816/what-can-i-do-about-a-slow-shared-internet-connection), so this one whould have no duplicate.